# API Tools location on Android 2.0 emulator?

Tags: android

I'm not sure if I'm simply something obvious (probably), but the API tools icon in the "manage applications" section of the phone isn't there.

I do see a Dev Tools icon on the main page, but that doesn't appear to have the same stuff in it.  Anyone know where I can find this section in Android 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must install the api demos from the sdk into your emulator.

find their location and import them into your eclipse installation. mine is at

```
/usr/local/android/platforms/android-2.0.1/samples/ApiDemos
```

that folder can be imported as an android project and deployed to your phone or emulator.